# SQL Oracle: How to make this complex case statement better in performance time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am relatively new to SQL Oracle and pulling data from our database. I appreciate any help or guidance.

I have two CTEs: Block Allocation and Service Usage. The CTE Block Allocation pulls the schedule of departments (scheduled date, start time, end time, number of hours, etc) and Service_Usage pulls all completed cases. I'm trying to identify cases that were completed in Red Room or Blue Room by matching the room number, schedule date, and whether the case was scheduled or began between Red/Blue Room's slot start and end time.

When I run the CTEs separately, I usually get my results in less than 10 seconds. I've added a case statement to CTE_Service_Usage and my query takes over 10 minutes. I'm not sure if it's the case statement or the union all at the end that causes my query to perform poorly. The case statement is clearly redundant.

I'm pulling my data from our database so it's difficult to provide sample data. Here's an example of the logic:

Red Room was scheduled in Room 6 from 7:30 to 12:30 on Jan 3rd, 2023. Case 1234 was completed in Room 6 from 8:30 to 11:30 on Jan 3rd, 2023. Case 1234 is identified as "Red Room". On the other hand, Case 2222 was scheduled to begin at 11:30, but began at 12:35. Case 2222 is identified as "Red Room", despite the case beginning after Red Room's scheduled slot.

Blue Room was scheduled in Room 2 from 12:30 to 17:00 on Jan 4th, 2023. Case 0000 was completed in Room 2 from 14:00 to 16:30 on Jan 4th, 2023. Case 0000 is identified as "Blue Room". Case 1111 was scheduled to begin at 12:30 in Room 2, but began at 12:25 (began 5 minutes earlier). Case 1111 is still identified as "Blue Room".

Please let me know how I can better prove my query. Thank you!

Here's my query:

```
WITH BLOCK_ALLOCATION AS (
    SELECT 
    SCHEDULE_DATE
    , CS.PROV_NAME AS ROOM_NM
    , CASE
        WHEN ROOM_ID IN ('150339507', '150339508', '150339509', '150339510', '150339512', '150339513')
        THEN 'AMBULATORY CENTER'
        ELSE 'MAIN OPERATING ROOM'
     END AS LOCATION
    , SLOT_START_TIME
    , SLOT_END_TIME
    , CASE 
        WHEN SLOT_END_TIME > SLOT_START_TIME 
        THEN ROUND(((SLOT_END_TIME - SLOT_START_TIME)*24)*60, 1) 
        ELSE ROUND((((SLOT_END_TIME+1)-SLOT_START_TIME)*24)*60, 1)
      END AS ASSIGNED_MINS_IN_OR
    , CASE
        WHEN ZC.NAME LIKE '%Robotics%'
        THEN 'Robotics'
        ELSE ZC.NAME
      END AS SERVICE
    , 'BLOCK' AS BLOCK_CASE
FROM V_OR_ROOM_TEMPLATE RT
     LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY_SER CS ON RT.ROOM_ID = CS.PROV_ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_OR_SERVICE ZC ON RT.SERVICE_C = ZC.SERVICE_C
WHERE
     TRUNC(SCHEDULE_DATE, 'Year') > TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'yyyy') - INTERVAL '2' YEAR
     AND SCHEDULE_DATE <= LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1))
     AND TRUNC(SCHEDULE_DATE) - TRUNC(SCHEDULE_DATE, 'IW') < 5
     AND ROOM_ID IN ('150123464', '150123465', '150123466', '150123467', '150123468', '150123469', '150123470', '150123471', '150123472', '150137692', '150135968', '150123474', '150339507', '150339508', '150339509', '150339510', '150339512', '150339513')
ORDER BY 1, 2
),

SERVICE_USAGE AS (
SELECT
    SUB.*
    , CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM BLOCK_ALLOCATION BA
        WHERE BA.SCHEDULE_DATE = SUB.SURGERY_DATE 
        AND BA.ROOM_NM = SUB.ROOM_NM
        AND BA.SERVICE = 'Blue Room'
        AND (((SUB.ROOM_IN_DTTM >= BA.SLOT_START_TIME AND (SUB.ROOM_IN_DTTM < BA.SLOT_END_TIME AND SUB.TIME_SCHEDULED < BA.SLOT_END_TIME))) 
            OR (SUB.TIME_SCHEDULED >= BA.SLOT_START_TIME AND (SUB.TIME_SCHEDULED < BA.SLOT_END_TIME AND SUB.ROOM_IN_DTTM < BA.SLOT_END_TIME)))
        ) THEN 'Blue Room' 
        WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM BLOCK_ALLOCATION BA
        WHERE BA.SCHEDULE_DATE = SUB.SURGERY_DATE 
        AND BA.ROOM_NM = SUB.ROOM_NM
        AND BA.SERVICE = 'Red Room'
        AND (((SUB.ROOM_IN_DTTM >= BA.SLOT_START_TIME AND (SUB.ROOM_IN_DTTM < BA.SLOT_END_TIME AND SUB.TIME_SCHEDULED < BA.SLOT_END_TIME))) 
            OR (SUB.TIME_SCHEDULED >= BA.SLOT_START_TIME AND (SUB.TIME_SCHEDULED < BA.SLOT_END_TIME AND SUB.ROOM_IN_DTTM < BA.SLOT_END_TIME)))
        ) THEN 'Red Room' 
        END RED_BLUE_ROOM
FROM (
    SELECT
        OL.LOG_ID
        , OL.CASE_ID
        , OL.LOG_NAME
        , LOC.LOC_NAME AS LOCATION
        , CS2.PROV_NAME AS ROOM_NM
        , OC.ADD_ON_CASE_YN
        , ZC.NAME AS STATUS_LOG
        , ZOCC.NAME AS CASE_CLASS
        , PC.NAME AS PAT_CLASS
        , OL.SURGERY_DATE
        , CASE
            WHEN ZOS.NAME = 'Obstetrics'
            THEN 'Gynecology'
            WHEN ZOS.NAME LIKE '%Robotics%'
            THEN 'Robotics'
            ELSE ZOS.NAME 
          END AS SERVICE
        , CS.PROV_NAME AS SURGEON
        , OP.PROC_NAME AS PRIMARY_PROCEDURE
        , OC.TIME_SCHEDULED
        , VLTE.PATIENT_IN_ROOM_DTTM AS ROOM_IN_DTTM
        , VLTE.PATIENT_OUT_ROOM_DTTM AS ROOM_OUT_DTTM
        , VLTE.MINUTES_IN_ROOM_TO_OUT_ROOM AS MINUTES_IN_OR
        , CASE
            WHEN VCRT.ROOM_OUT_TO_IN IS NULL OR VCRT.ROOM_OUT_TO_IN < 0
            THEN 0
            WHEN VCRT.ROOM_OUT_TO_IN > 60
            THEN 60
            ELSE VCRT.ROOM_OUT_TO_IN
          END AS ROOM_OUT_TO_IN
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY OL.LOG_ID ORDER BY OL.LOG_ID, OLAS.LINE) AS RWNUM
     , 'CASE' AS BLOCK_CASE
     FROM 
        OR_LOG OL
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_OR_STATUS ZC ON OL.STATUS_C = ZC.STATUS_C
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_OR_CASE_CLASS ZOCC ON OL.CASE_CLASS_C = ZOCC.CASE_CLASS_C
        LEFT OUTER JOIN OR_LOG_ALL_SURG OLAS ON OL.LOG_ID = OLAS.LOG_ID AND OLAS.ROLE_C = 1 AND OLAS.PANEL = 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN OR_LOG_ALL_PROC OLAP ON OL.LOG_ID = OLAP.LOG_ID AND OLAP.LINE = 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN V_LOG_TIMING_EVENTS VLTE ON OL.LOG_ID = VLTE.LOG_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN V_CASE_ROOM_TURNOVER VCRT ON OL.LOG_ID = VCRT.PRE_LOG_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN OR_CASE OC ON OL.LOG_ID = OC.LOG_ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_OR_SERVICE ZOS ON OLAS.SERVICE_C = ZOS.SERVICE_C
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY_SER CS ON OLAS.SURG_ID = CS.PROV_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN OR_PROC OP ON OLAP.OR_PROC_ID = OP.OR_PROC_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY_LOC LOC ON OC.LOC_ID = LOC.LOC_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_PAT_CLASS PC ON OL.PAT_TYPE_C = PC.ADT_PAT_CLASS_C
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY_SER CS2 ON OL.ROOM_ID = CS2.PROV_ID
     WHERE
        OL.STATUS_C IN (2, 3, 5)
        AND TRUNC(OL.SURGERY_DATE, 'Year') > TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'yyyy') - INTERVAL '2' YEAR
        AND OL.SURGERY_DATE <= LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1))
        AND TRUNC(OL.SURGERY_DATE) - TRUNC(OL.SURGERY_DATE, 'IW') < 5
        AND OC.LOC_ID IN (12194, 121122248)
    ORDER BY 
        OL.SURGERY_DATE DESC
    ) SUB
  WHERE
    SUB.RWNUM = 1
),

BLOCK_CASES as (
SELECT 
    LOG_ID
    , LOG_NAME
    , LOCATION
    , ROOM_NM
    , ADD_ON_CASE_YN
    , STATUS_LOG
    , CASE_CLASS
    , PAT_CLASS
    , SURGERY_DATE
    , TIME_SCHEDULED
    , ROOM_IN_DTTM
    , ROOM_OUT_DTTM
    , MINUTES_IN_OR
    , SERVICE
    , SURGEON
    , NULL AS ASSIGNED_MINS_IN_OR
    , PRIMARY_PROCEDURE
    , ROOM_OUT_TO_IN
    , BLOCK_CASE
FROM 
    SERVICE_USAGE
WHERE
    TIME_SCHEDULED < TRUNC(TIME_SCHEDULED) + INTERVAL '17:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND
    AND MINUTES_IN_OR IS NOT NULL
    AND SERVICE != 'Gastroenterology'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    NULL AS LOG_ID
    , NULL AS LOG_NAME
    , LOCATION
    , ROOM_NM
    , NULL AS ADD_ON_CASE_YN
    , NULL AS STATUS_LOG
    , NULL AS CASE_CLASS
    , NULL AS PAT_CLASS
    , SCHEDULE_DATE AS SURGERY_DATE
    , NULL AS TIME_SCHEDULED
    , SLOT_START_TIME AS ROOM_IN_DTTM
    , SLOT_END_TIME AS ROOM_OUT_DTTM
    , NULL AS MINUTES_IN_OR
    , SERVICE
    , NULL AS SURGEON
    , ASSIGNED_MINS_IN_OR
    , NULL AS PRIMARY_PROCEDURE
    , NULL AS ROOM_OUT_TO_IN
    , BLOCK_CASE
FROM 
    BLOCK_ALLOCATION
WHERE
    ASSIGNED_MINS_IN_OR <= 570
)
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT ...) WHEN EXISTS (SELECT ...)` is your pain point. Rewrite using a join.

Comment: @Bohemian, That's a place to look, but if proper indexing is in place it doesn't have to be the problem area.

Comment: @Husna, your problem can be literally anywhere. Unfortunately nobody can tune queries (especially ones that complex!) against tables they don't know with data they don't know in a database they don't know. There's too much that goes into performance tuning to get anything but guesses from this forum. Instead, I suggest you engage your DBA for assistance. Otherwise, look into the standard performance tuning tools Oracle has, like a SQL Monitor report, OEM, ASH, etc.

Comment: do not waste effort by ordering results in the CTEs (e.g. `ORDER BY 1, 2` and `ORDER BY  OL.SURGERY_DATE DESC`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like below:

```
WITH BLOCK_ALLOCATION AS (
SELECT 
SCHEDULE_DATE
, CS.PROV_NAME AS ROOM_NM
, CASE
    WHEN ROOM_ID IN ('150339507', '150339508', '150339509', '150339510', '150339512', '150339513')
    THEN 'AMBULATORY CENTER'
    ELSE 'MAIN OPERATING ROOM'
 END AS LOCATION
, SLOT_START_TIME
, SLOT_END_TIME
, CASE 
    WHEN SLOT_END_TIME > SLOT_START_TIME 
    THEN ROUND(((SLOT_END_TIME - SLOT_START_TIME)*24)*60, 1) 
    ELSE ROUND((((SLOT_END_TIME+1)-SLOT_START_TIME)*24)*60, 1)
  END AS ASSIGNED_MINS_IN_OR
, CASE
    WHEN ZC.NAME LIKE '%Robotics%'
    THEN 'Robotics'
    ELSE ZC.NAME
  END AS SERVICE
  , 'BLOCK' AS BLOCK_CASE
 FROM V_OR_ROOM_TEMPLATE RT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY_SER CS ON RT.ROOM_ID = CS.PROV_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_OR_SERVICE ZC ON RT.SERVICE_C = ZC.SERVICE_C
 WHERE
   TRUNC(SCHEDULE_DATE, 'Year') > TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'yyyy') - INTERVAL '2' YEAR
   AND SCHEDULE_DATE <= LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1))
   AND TRUNC(SCHEDULE_DATE) - TRUNC(SCHEDULE_DATE, 'IW') < 5
   AND ROOM_ID IN ('150123464', '150123465', '150123466', '150123467', '150123468', '150123469', '150123470', '150123471', '150123472', '150137692', '150135968', '150123474', '150339507', '150339508', '150339509', '150339510', '150339512', '150339513')
ORDER BY 1, 2
)
,balloc as (
   SELECT BA.SCHEDULE_DATE, BA.ROOM_NM, BA.SLOT_START_TIME, BA.SLOT_END_TIME
   FROM BLOCK_ALLOCATION BA 
 )
,sub as (
   SELECT
     OL.LOG_ID
     , OL.CASE_ID
     , OL.LOG_NAME
     , LOC.LOC_NAME AS LOCATION
     , CS2.PROV_NAME AS ROOM_NM
     , OC.ADD_ON_CASE_YN
        , ZC.NAME AS STATUS_LOG
        , ZOCC.NAME AS CASE_CLASS
        , PC.NAME AS PAT_CLASS
        , OL.SURGERY_DATE
        , CASE
            WHEN ZOS.NAME = 'Obstetrics'
            THEN 'Gynecology'
            WHEN ZOS.NAME LIKE '%Robotics%'
            THEN 'Robotics'
            ELSE ZOS.NAME 
          END AS SERVICE
        , CS.PROV_NAME AS SURGEON
        , OP.PROC_NAME AS PRIMARY_PROCEDURE
        , OC.TIME_SCHEDULED
        , VLTE.PATIENT_IN_ROOM_DTTM AS ROOM_IN_DTTM
        , VLTE.PATIENT_OUT_ROOM_DTTM AS ROOM_OUT_DTTM
        , VLTE.MINUTES_IN_ROOM_TO_OUT_ROOM AS MINUTES_IN_OR
        , CASE
            WHEN VCRT.ROOM_OUT_TO_IN IS NULL OR VCRT.ROOM_OUT_TO_IN < 0
            THEN 0
            WHEN VCRT.ROOM_OUT_TO_IN > 60
            THEN 60
            ELSE VCRT.ROOM_OUT_TO_IN
          END AS ROOM_OUT_TO_IN
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY OL.LOG_ID ORDER BY OL.LOG_ID, OLAS.LINE) AS RWNUM
     , 'CASE' AS BLOCK_CASE
     FROM 
        OR_LOG OL
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_OR_STATUS ZC ON OL.STATUS_C = ZC.STATUS_C
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_OR_CASE_CLASS ZOCC ON OL.CASE_CLASS_C = ZOCC.CASE_CLASS_C
        LEFT OUTER JOIN OR_LOG_ALL_SURG OLAS ON OL.LOG_ID = OLAS.LOG_ID AND OLAS.ROLE_C = 1 AND OLAS.PANEL = 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN OR_LOG_ALL_PROC OLAP ON OL.LOG_ID = OLAP.LOG_ID AND OLAP.LINE = 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN V_LOG_TIMING_EVENTS VLTE ON OL.LOG_ID = VLTE.LOG_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN V_CASE_ROOM_TURNOVER VCRT ON OL.LOG_ID = VCRT.PRE_LOG_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN OR_CASE OC ON OL.LOG_ID = OC.LOG_ID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_OR_SERVICE ZOS ON OLAS.SERVICE_C = ZOS.SERVICE_C
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY_SER CS ON OLAS.SURG_ID = CS.PROV_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN OR_PROC OP ON OLAP.OR_PROC_ID = OP.OR_PROC_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY_LOC LOC ON OC.LOC_ID = LOC.LOC_ID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ZC_PAT_CLASS PC ON OL.PAT_TYPE_C = PC.ADT_PAT_CLASS_C
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CLARITY_SER CS2 ON OL.ROOM_ID = CS2.PROV_ID
     WHERE
        OL.STATUS_C IN (2, 3, 5)
        AND TRUNC(OL.SURGERY_DATE, 'Year') > TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'yyyy') - INTERVAL '2' YEAR
        AND OL.SURGERY_DATE <= LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1))
        AND TRUNC(OL.SURGERY_DATE) - TRUNC(OL.SURGERY_DATE, 'IW') < 5
        AND OC.LOC_ID IN (12194, 121122248)
    ORDER BY 
        OL.SURGERY_DATE DESC

  )
  ,SERVICE_USAGE AS (
     SELECT
     SUB.*
     ,balloc.service END RED_BLUE_ROOM
   FROM SUB
   left join balloc on (BAlloc.SCHEDULE_DATE = SUB.SURGERY_DATE and BAlloc.ROOM_NM = SUB.ROOM_NM
     AND (((SUB.ROOM_IN_DTTM >= BAlloc.SLOT_START_TIME AND (SUB.ROOM_IN_DTTM < BAlloc.SLOT_END_TIME AND SUB.TIME_SCHEDULED < BAlloc.SLOT_END_TIME))) 
            OR (SUB.TIME_SCHEDULED >= BAlloc.SLOT_START_TIME AND (SUB.TIME_SCHEDULED < BAlloc.SLOT_END_TIME AND SUB.ROOM_IN_DTTM < BAlloc.SLOT_END_TIME))))
    WHERE
    SUB.RWNUM = 1
),

BLOCK_CASES as (
SELECT 
    LOG_ID
    , LOG_NAME
    , LOCATION
    , ROOM_NM
    , ADD_ON_CASE_YN
    , STATUS_LOG
    , CASE_CLASS
    , PAT_CLASS
    , SURGERY_DATE
    , TIME_SCHEDULED
    , ROOM_IN_DTTM
    , ROOM_OUT_DTTM
    , MINUTES_IN_OR
    , SERVICE
    , SURGEON
    , NULL AS ASSIGNED_MINS_IN_OR
    , PRIMARY_PROCEDURE
    , ROOM_OUT_TO_IN
    , BLOCK_CASE
FROM 
    SERVICE_USAGE
WHERE
    TIME_SCHEDULED < TRUNC(TIME_SCHEDULED) + INTERVAL '17:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND
    AND MINUTES_IN_OR IS NOT NULL
    AND SERVICE != 'Gastroenterology'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    NULL AS LOG_ID
    , NULL AS LOG_NAME
    , LOCATION
    , ROOM_NM
    , NULL AS ADD_ON_CASE_YN
    , NULL AS STATUS_LOG
    , NULL AS CASE_CLASS
    , NULL AS PAT_CLASS
    , SCHEDULE_DATE AS SURGERY_DATE
    , NULL AS TIME_SCHEDULED
    , SLOT_START_TIME AS ROOM_IN_DTTM
    , SLOT_END_TIME AS ROOM_OUT_DTTM
    , NULL AS MINUTES_IN_OR
    , SERVICE
    , NULL AS SURGEON
    , ASSIGNED_MINS_IN_OR
    , NULL AS PRIMARY_PROCEDURE
    , NULL AS ROOM_OUT_TO_IN
    , BLOCK_CASE
  FROM 
    BLOCK_ALLOCATION
  WHERE
    ASSIGNED_MINS_IN_OR <= 570
  )
```

;

Still, not sure whether there will not be necessary one more row_number() or to replace the previous row_number() with a different one. Not having the data, I can't test. An explain-plan may also help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if your issue is the query performance, or the unexpected results. Without sample data and an explain plan, I've looked at the unexpected results.

The `service_usage` CTE is being used to decide whether an appointment was `red room` or `blue room`, but the 2 highlighted cases are neither. The 2 parts of the CASE are identical apart from the room name, and the core code is:

```
AND (((sub.room_in_dttm >= ba.slot_start_time AND 
          (sub.room_in_dttm < ba.slot_end_time AND sub.time_scheduled < ba.slot_end_time)))
       OR (sub.time_scheduled >= ba.slot_start_time AND 
              (sub.time_scheduled < ba.slot_end_time AND sub.room_in_dttm < ba.slot_end_time)))
```

Case 2222 was scheduled for 11:30 (red room) but began at 12:35 (blue room), so neither room apples. Case 1111 was scheduled for 12:30 (blue room) but began at 12:25 (red room), so again neither room applies.

We don't have the main part of the query, so we don't know what happens with the `red_blue_room` output from the `service_usage` CTE, but it is essentially undefined.

I would suggest removing all the extra code and focus on the room code, making `sub` a separate CTE and then using something like this CTE:

```
service_room AS (
    SELECT ba.service
    FROM   block_allocation ba
    WHERE  ba.schedule_date = sub.surgery_date
    AND    ba.room_nm = sub.room_nm
    AND (((sub.room_in_dttm >= ba.slot_start_time AND 
              (sub.room_in_dttm < ba.slot_end_time AND sub.time_scheduled < ba.slot_end_time)))
           OR (sub.time_scheduled >= ba.slot_start_time AND 
                  (sub.time_scheduled < ba.slot_end_time AND sub.room_in_dttm < ba.slot_end_time)))
```